# Saiku Memory Issues after Upgrading to MySQL 5.7

Tags: saiku

We are running the standalone version of Saiku 2.6. Since upgrading our server to MySQL 5.7 most queries that we run in Saiku (unless they are very basic) stall out and throw the following error:

**OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**

Is anyone aware of compatibility issues with older versions of Saiku with MySQL 5.7? Is there anything else that might cause this issue?